# How can I change the color of a row in a grid when the cursor is over that row?

Tags: jquery

I have rows in a table and I would like to change the background color of these when the cursor is over them. I saw some similar posts but what I would like to use is jQuery. Is there a simple way I can do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

The `hover` function should make this easy:

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("newColorClass");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("newColorClass");
});
```

The first function gets fired when your hover *in*, the second one fires when you hover *out*.  And `newColorClass` is of course something like

```
.newColorClass { background-color: 'red' }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfjcR/1/)

Comment: But what if I move from row to row in the grid? I am looking for something that will make the color move. I guess I don't quite understand when removeClass will get implemented using your syntax.

Comment: Did you run the fiddle?  removeClass gets run when you hover *out* of the row.  So when you hover your mouse, the row gets colored.  When you take your mouse off the row, the color goes away.  Is that what you were wanting?